# Flyway callback classpath

Tags: maven, classpath, flyway

I'm using Flyway Maven Plugin to do my migrations.

I wrote a callback class to go in a resource directory and run the function/procedure files. However it doesn't find some files in the resource folder.

I added the function files in the folder `src/main/resources/db/functions`.

In my flyway callback code, I call the following code, but I get a `null` url.

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("db/functions/mySQL.sql");
```

I also tryed some variations of getting the system resourse, like add `classpath` before and some variations to get the resources.

The same code worked if I created a class with the main method using the Flyway Java API, it seems a classloader problem in Maven. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

Option 1:

- Don't forget to call compile to make sure the resources are available on the classpath
- Use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`

Option 2:

- Use a FileReader